# Why don't I see my TODOs for my PHP files in Eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, task, eclipse-pdt, todo

Why don't I see my TODOs for my PHP files in Eclipse?

I ran into this issue in PDT, I just wanted to put the answer up in case someone else did too.

Comment: Nooooooooo make your answer an answer below in "Answer your question" (please)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ran into this issue in PDT, I just wanted to put the answer up in case someone else did too.

- ANSWER * Although PHP doesn't really need to compile in your IDE, you need to "build" your project for TODO tags to be automatically added as tasks. If you enable Project->"Build Automatically" in Eclipse your TODOs will always become tasks upon saving your file.

Comment: To be clear, "Project" -> "Build Automatically" is a menu option, not a project setting. I was right-clicking on the project in the PHP Explorer panel, choosing "Properties" from the context menu, and wondering why I didn't see the option. Also, the "Build Automatically" option appears to be global, i.e., it cannot be set on a per-project basis.

Comment: @BenJohnson - THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work for me (using Eclipse with the Aptana plugin) I had to enable "PHP" as a Project Nature in my project properties, under Project | Properties | Project Natures

I had it set to "Web" and I was only getting TODOs from my Javascript files.